# How to get last auto increment value in mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a javafx project where a user can register as either a driver or a client. For this, I created 3 tables in a mysql database, a general one for all users and 2 specific ones for the drivers and the clients. When a new user registers he is placed in the `database_user` table and, depending on his selected role, he is also placed in either `database_client` or `database_driver`. The problem is that the specific tables should have a column storing the primary key value (autoincrement value) from the general table, for easier communication.

```
public static void registerClient(ActionEvent event, String username, String password, String role, String name, int age, String gender, String email)
    {
        /*
          these variables are the connections to the mysql database
          */

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement psInsert = null;
        PreparedStatement psInsertClient = null;
        PreparedStatement psCheckUserAlreadyExists = null;
        //PreparedStatement psCheckEmailAlreadyUsed = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{
            /*
              this will attempt to establish a connection with the db
              */

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://lazarov.go.ro:3306/RideShare", "root", "chocolate");
            psCheckUserAlreadyExists = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM database_user WHERE username = ?");
            psCheckUserAlreadyExists.setString(1, username);
            //psCheckEmailAlreadyUsed = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user_database WHERE email = ? ");
            //psCheckEmailAlreadyUsed.setString(7, email);
            resultSet = psCheckUserAlreadyExists.executeQuery();

            /*
              check if the resultSet is empty
              if true => username already taken => notify user about this
             */

            if(resultSet.isBeforeFirst())
            {
                System.out.println("Username already taken!");
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setContentText("User already exists!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            else
            {
                psInsert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database_user (username, password, role, name, age, gender, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                psInsert.setString(1, username);
                psInsert.setString(2, password);
                psInsert.setString(3, role);
                psInsert.setString(4, name);
                psInsert.setInt(5, age);
                psInsert.setString(6, gender);
                psInsert.setString(7, email);
                psInsert.executeUpdate();
                
                ResultSet rs = null;
                psInsert = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT max(user_id) FROM database_user");
                rs = psInsert.executeQuery();
                // driver specific
                int userId = resultSet.getInt("max(user_id)"); // this is where the error occurs

                //Connection connectionDriver = null;


                psInsertClient = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database_client (user_id, ride_requested, location, destination, corresponding_driver_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                psInsertClient.setInt(1, userId);
                psInsertClient.setBoolean(2, false);
                psInsertClient.setString(3, null);
                psInsertClient.setString(4, null);
                psInsertClient.setInt(5, 0);

                changeScene(event, "client.fxml", "RideShare - Client", username, role, name, age, gender, email);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            /*
              close db connections to avoid memory leaks
              */

            if(resultSet != null)
            {
                try{
                    resultSet.close();
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(psCheckUserAlreadyExists != null)
            {
                try{
                    psCheckUserAlreadyExists.close();
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(psInsert != null)
            {
                try {
                    psInsert.close();
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(psInsertClient != null)
            {
                try {
                    psInsertClient.close();
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(connection != null)
            {
                try{
                    connection.close();
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I try to create a new user, the user is added in the `database_user` correctly, but throws the error "wrong row position" when trying to store it in the "database_client" as well. How can I successfully get the last autoincremented value from the general table?

Comment: Query the table for max value `select max(user_id) from database_user`  I'm sure there's an internal sequence you could query as well, but accessing that might trigger an increment.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @AshishPatil ```java.sql.SQLDataException: wrong row position```

Comment: *How can I successfully get the last autoincremented value from the general table?* Overall value or one within current connection?

Comment: @Akina the one for the user that's just been added, because each time a user is added to the general table it will also be added to one of the 2 specific tables

Comment: *If I try to create a new user, the user is added in the database_user correctly, but throws the error "wrong row position" when trying to store it in the "database_client" as well.* You must not retrieve "last" AI value but select actual value from the table using known row values as conditions.

Comment: *for the user that's just been added* This means "in the connection". You may use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` if you insert only one row for the user.

Comment: I've also tried using @Ryan's suggestion but I'm probably not doing it correctly because I'm getting the same error

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname; for all 3 tables and we will probably see your definition error.